# How to find out which network service is being using (NetworkManager, otherwise, etc.)?

Tags: networking

I see a lot of information on NetworkManager for Ubuntu, but on an installation I'm working on right now it seems like NetworkManager isn't present (no `nmcli`, no `NetworkManager.service` unit).

How do you go about finding out *which* network service is installed and currently used?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu please ?

Comment: Is this a Server installation or a Desktop installation?  If it's a Server installation of 18.04 or newer, it's using Netplan to configure interfaces.  If it's a 16.04 machine it's using `ifupdown` and `/etc/network/interfaces` and the kernel to configure your interfaces.  If it's a GUI install, it's probably using Network Manager

Comment: Look at `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` renderer.

Comment: @cmak.fr this is 18.04.

Comment: @heynnema that would be cloud-init. And it's network version 2 so looks like netplan? But isn't netplan just a layer on top of NetworkManager and networkd?

Comment: @ThomasWard this is a server installation. But isn't netplan a layer on top of NetworkManager and networkd?

Comment: @ThomasStringer netplan will set the config for networkd in your setup.  So only alter the netplan configs.

Comment: @ThomasWard this is more of a question of, what is the underlying network service? How to find out if it is NetworkManager, networkd, or otherwise? I guess just looking at running services..?

Comment: @ThomasStringer no, looking at the netplan configuration will tell you.  Either it's Network Manager or `networkd` and would be shown in the 'renderer' field in the YAML.

Comment: @ThomasWard in this case, it is a cloud-init yaml in /etc/netplan/*.yaml so there is no renderer field.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`. If you don't see a renderer, then you're using netplan (as server installations do), not NetworkManager. And no, netplan is not a layer on top of NM.